# Is there a Firefox Add-on for automatic redirection based on XPath?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, redirection

I would like to have Firefox add-on which recognizes a website page and automatically redirects to link in the page identified its XPath.

One example for this is on the news aggregator sites like DZone. Whenever I click a DZone RSS feed's link it goes the DZone website and only after clicking the link it jumps to the actual blog/news page. I want to automatically jump to the actual content/blog/news page when I land the DZone site.

Comment: For redirection based on url patterns, see: [Can I get my browser to automatically redirect on some pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/351771/can-i-get-my-browser-to-automatically-redirect-on-some-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds it would be easy to create [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) userscript to do so.

Greasemonkey scripts are launched only on URLs matching the expreession you provide (so you can write sth like "http://dzone.com/*), and they are executed once page is loaded (top be more more detailed: when `DOMContentLoaded` event fires).

Writing a script should be easy with just plain JavaScript and XPath.
You need to read some value by XPath like you say, and then to do the redirect, set `window.location = ...`.

If I understood you correctly, you can use the following code - works for me in Firefox 7.0.1 / Greasemonkey 0.9.11

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Dzone Automatic Redirect
// @namespace      userscript_dzone
// @include        http://www.dzone.com/links/rss/*
// ==/UserScript==

   var XPathTools = 
   {
      getElementByXpath : function(xpath, referenceNode)
      {
         var xPathResult = document.evaluate (xpath, referenceNode, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
         return xPathResult.singleNodeValue;
      }
   };

   var xpath = "//div[@id='linkDetails']//div[@class='ldTitle']/a";
   var url = XPathTools.getElementByXpath(xpath,document);
   window.location = url;
```